# How implement LiveData Room in Clean Architecture with ViewModel + UseCase + Repository + Dao

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, clean-architecture

I want to ask if you know what is the best practice to use coroutines in a clean architecture way.

My implementation uses a presentation layer (fragment + ViewModel), domain (Entities + UseCases) and data layer (Repository with Room)

For example, one part of the project update a RecyclerView from a Room table when a new entry is setting.

I have a Dao with a LiveData List in data layer:

```
@Dao
interface UsersDao {
    @Insert
    suspend fun insertUser(user: UserDB): Long

    @Query("SELECT * FROM " + USERSTABLE)
    fun getUsers(): LiveData<List<UserDB>>
}
```

The User repository in data layer:

```
val users: LiveData<List<UserEntity>> = Transformations.map(
    dao.getUsers()
) { it.map { mapperDBtoEntity.mapFrom(it) } }

override fun getUsers(): LiveData<List<UserEntity>> {
    return users
}
```

The Use Case in domain layer:

```
class GetUsersUseCase (
    private val usersRepository: UsersRepository
) {
    fun invoke() = usersRepository.getUsers()
}
```

And well finally the call in the ViewModel (presentation layer)

```
var users: LiveData<List<UserEntity>> = getUsersUseCase.invoke()
```

My doubt or question is I'm not sure if I'm implementing the right way to connect the User livedata in the ViewModel with the repository through the Use Case.

In the web I only saw examples that don't have a Use Case, they connect the viewModel directly with the repository.

Comment: this question is entirely based on opinion, there isn't one single best way to do any architecture, they're just guidelines